# Does "to grow to like" imply previous dislike?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does the phrase *to grow to like* imply that one had not liked it before he started liking it. As in the expression:

> I *grew to like* jogging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly speaking, it implies indifference or unawareness; I would not expect an active dislike unless it were specifically mentioned, or unless the subject matter is widely understood to be unpleasant.

Answer (score 3):

No, not really.  "I grew to like" does not imply or suggest any specific previous state except less than "like", such as 'just ok', ambivalence, or actual dislike.

> George hated vegetables as a kid, but he grew to like broccoli as an adult.
>
> George grew to like shuffle board after he retired.  (He may never have played before.)